# PHP Twig translation files

Tags: php, internationalization, twig, translation

I am using the twig template engine. I added the I18n extension for translating but it is not working. It shows always "password".

Here is my code:

```
// index.php
putenv('LC_ALL=fr_FR');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

bindtextdomain('app', 'locale');
bind_textdomain_codeset('app', 'UTF-8');
textdomain('app');

require_once 'lib/vendor/autoload.php';

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'cache' => false,
    'debug' => true
));
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extensions_Extension_I18n());


// templates/index.html
{% include 'header.html' %}
    Translate that: {% trans "password" %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}

// locale/fr_FR/app.yml
password: mot de passe
```

Any ideas?
I am not using the symfony framework.

Comment: is it case sensitive?

Comment: "Password" !== "password"...!?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I corrected it.
The problem is still there. I think that the language .yml file is not loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that this extension support yml? [Here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html) says only about gettext (it is MO/PO files as I know).

Comment: hm, if I use locale/fr_FR/app.po contents msgid and msgstr it does not work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Create correct PO file. Or try take this `app.po`:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: \n"
"PO-Revision-Date: \n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Language: fr_FR\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.7\n"

#: templates/1.php:3
msgid "password"
msgstr "mot de passe"
```

#### 2. Based on `app.po` generate `app.mo`. For example with [po2mo.net](http://po2mo.net/) tool.

#### 3. Place `app.mo` to `locale/fr_FR/LC_MESSAGES` dir.

Comment: Thank you!!
I followed your instruction and added UTF-8 and now it works:

putenv('LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');

Place of app.mo: locale/fr_FR.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES

Comment: Note that instead of po2mo.net, you should install the gettext tools locally and do all that on the command line. The tools are all there...